# Surveymonkey REST API - Skip logic

Tags: logic, skip, surveymonkey

I am investigating Survey Monkey as a way to complete a survey-based project using the REST API.

The questions would need to branch (as in if Answer B given to Question 1, then go to Question 3 etc).

Looking at the REST API documentation, it seems that I can query a page to get a list of questions using:

/surveys/{id}/pages/{id}/questions

But what happens if I implement skip logic? Is there a way to find out if this logic exists and if so go to a different page/question? Does the API cover this?

I am currently using a free account so cannot implement skip logic at the moment in any case, but would like to know if this is possible before I upgrade.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip logic is not currently available through the API. We do have intention to provide the skip logic information at `/surveys/{id}/pages/{id}/questions` as you've mentioned but there is no ETA for that at the moment.

Also, we don't intend to allow skip logic to be followed/validated when submitting responses through the API.

Comment: Just over a year has passed, is there any update regarding skip logic being added to the SurveyMonkey API?

Comment: It's 2020 now. more than 4 years since. Any progress?